# Switch Not Triggering

Tags: javascript

I have five images.  When I click on one I want an alert box to open.  Just for testing now.  It's not triggering anything.  Any suggestions as why its not?  Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:image").click(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
setSearch( $(this).val() );})
})


function setSearch()
{
    switch(this){
        case "Place":
            alert("Case is Place"); 
            break;
        case "Cuisine":
            alert("Case is Cuisine");
            break;
        case "City":
            alert("Case is City");
            break;
        case "State":
            alert("Case is State");
            break;
        case "ZipCode":
            alert("Case is ZipCode");   
            break;  
        }
}
```

On the image

```
 <td width="192"><div align="center"> <input name="Place" type = "image" id="Place" value = "Place" src="../Glass-Place.jpg" alt="Place"
```

Comment: What is `n` in `$(n).val()`? Did you mean `$(this).val()`?

Comment: The id of the image.  See revised code for what is on the image.

Comment: The way you call `setSearch`, `this` refers to `window`. Don't you mean to `switch` the first argument passed to the function?

Comment: I just figured it out.  See the answer.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this happens because `n` is not defined in `click` handler.

Try the following instead:

```
$("input:image").click(function(e) {
    setSearch(this.value);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your change of •setSearch• method is invalid. Rollback to the first version.

Comment: @ME-dia: You should accept this answer. Also, there is not really a point in posting VisioN's answer as your own.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:image").click(function(e) {
var n = setSearch(this.value);
e.preventDefault();
});})
```

And this....

```
function setSearch(n)
{
    switch(n){
        case "Place":
            alert("Case is Place"); 
            break;
        case "Cuisine":
            alert("Case is Cuisine");
            break;
        case "City":
            alert("Case is City");
            break;
        case "State":
            alert("Case is State");
            break;
        case "ZipCode":
            alert("Case is ZipCode");   
            break;  
        }
}
```